# If I click "p" then open file

Tags: python

I am trying to run different files in one main file... So when I click "p" i should be able to open my other file and play in it...but an error message always comes when i do this...

```
def play(self):
    with open("TheUltimatePONG.py", "r") as the_file:
        self._outputArea.insert("1.0", the_file.read())

wn.onkey(play, "p")
wn.listen()
```

An error comes saying:

```
TypeError: play() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I don't understand what it means.

Comment: is this function in a class?

Comment: Why do you think `play` should have a `self` parameter?

Comment: We don't know what this `wn` is, since you haven't included your `import` lines or tagged for a library. A question should ideally include a [mcve] -- the *shortest* code that can be run *without changes* to see the same problem. "Run without changes" means including your imports -- otherwise, we don't know what we need to install before running it ourselves, or which libraries' API documentation to check against.

Comment: wn is turtle.Screen()

Comment: Edit the question to comply with the MCVE definition. Until that's done, answers can't be tested in a context guaranteed to be equivalent to your own.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is very explicit:

```
TypeError: play() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Means that your `play()` function is defined to expect a `self` argument, but isn't passed one when it's actually invoked.

---

If `wn.onkey(play, "p")` establishes a callback which invokes `play()` with no arguments, then don't define it to expect a `self` argument!

That is to say, change:

```
# This takes a "self" argument, which usually only makes sense for methods, not functions.
def play(self):
```

to:

```
# This version does not expect any arguments at all.
def play():
```

Comment: I'm not available for one-on-one tutoring, except for people I know in person. "Not working" isn't a very useful problem report. Same error? Different one?